# Reverse ASCII checksum algorithm

Tags: decryption

I am looking to reverse engineer what appears to be a 24-bit ASCII checksum.  I tried the standard CRC 16 and 32-bit checksums and they don't work.  Any pointers would be appreciated.  Here is some samples:

```
CMD21415A00M40C153S117!D0H$
CMD21415A00M40C197S439!EJG$
CMD21415A00M40C239S825!CIB$
CMD21415A00M40C239S029!FHZ$
CMD21415A00M40C197S275!BJE$
CMD21415A00M40C153S302!N7W$
CMD21415A00M40C153S141!A4I$
CMD21415A00M40C197S266!8KE$
CMD21415A00M40C197S714!RD0$
```

I believe for each line the checksum (3 ASCII characters between '!' and '$') is for the ASCII data between 'CMD' and '!'.  It does not seems to match any of basic checksum algorithms that I am familiar with.

Comment: Please add a bit more context as to where did you find this, any program or device? What's the CMD supposed to be?

Comment: The data for a power control device that accepts serial data.  I believe 'CMD' indicates command instructions.

Comment: OK, here's a question. Have you ever observed the same command instruction multiple times, and was the checksum the same?

Comment: I checked data I collected and unfortunately did not find any repeat command packets.  One thing I did try to send some command packets with invalid checksum and I did get a error message saying it is invalid CRC.  So, I am wondering what is the likely standard CRC algorithm/type (e.g. 16-bit, 32-bit, etc.) that would be used then converted to the 3 character ASCII checksum as I doubt a complete custom CRC algorithm was developed.